Thousands of phantom contacts being created
I have a CiviCRM 5.76.2 installation on a WordPress 6.6.1 site (not on wordpress.com).  I just noticed that I have over 4,000 contacts in CiviCRM that have my email address (and nothing else) as contact info, and the number is growing every few minutes:
mysql> select count(*) from civicrm_contact c where id in
   (select contact_id from civicrm_email where email='example@gmail.com');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4226 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from civicrm_contact c where id in
   (select contact_id from civicrm_email where email='example@gmail.com');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4228 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select c.created_date, c.modified_date
   from civicrm_contact c, civicrm_email e
   where e.contact_id = c.id and email='example@gmail.com'
   order by c.modified_date desc limit 10;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| created_date        | modified_date       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2024-09-02 17:51:02 | 2024-09-02 17:51:03 |
| 2024-09-02 17:51:01 | 2024-09-02 17:51:01 |
| 2024-09-02 17:50:40 | 2024-09-02 17:50:40 |
| 2024-09-02 17:50:39 | 2024-09-02 17:50:39 |
| 2024-09-02 17:50:38 | 2024-09-02 17:50:38 |
| 2024-09-02 17:50:36 | 2024-09-02 17:50:37 |
| 2024-09-02 17:48:39 | 2024-09-02 17:48:39 |
| 2024-09-02 17:48:38 | 2024-09-02 17:48:38 |
| 2024-09-02 17:48:37 | 2024-09-02 17:48:37 |
| 2024-09-02 17:48:36 | 2024-09-02 17:48:36 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)

This is a very low-traffic site, there's definitely no other person inserting these users.  There must be an automated process doing this somewhere - but I can't figure out what it is.
I only have two active Scheduled Jobs in CiviCRM, and they just run daily & hourly:

And my system cron only has the following jobs (this is the contents of the shell script that executes), run hourly:
~/private/bin/cv api job.execute --cwd=/home/example/www/wp

BACKUP_DIR=~/private/backup/wordpress-site
BIN_DIR=~/private/python-venv/bin

cd ~/www/wp && /usr/local/bin/wp db export - | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/full-db-$(date '+%FT%T%z').sql.gz"
"$BIN_DIR/rotate-backups" --hourly=10 --daily=7 --weekly=5 --monthly=12 --yearly=10 --include "full-db-*" "$BACKUP_DIR"

cd ~/www && tar -czf "$BACKUP_DIR/files-$(date '+%FT%T%z').tar.gz" wp
"$BIN_DIR/rotate-backups" --hourly=10 --daily=7 --weekly=5 --monthly=12 --yearly=10 --include "files-*" "$BACKUP_DIR"

There are no logs at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Flogviewer that shed any light.
What could possibly be doing this?  Can I turn on some extra logging to show what's creating contacts?

Check both (a) the civi dedupe rules (are they weird?) and (b) if there is some mismatch between the civi contact's email, the email stored in civicrm_uf_match, and the email for the associated wordpress user.

If that doesn't show anything you can add some code to an extension that implements hook_civicrm_post and log a backtrace with CRM_Core_Error::backtrace('hello', true); when the object is Contact and "op" is Create.

Hmm - so apparently the WordPress User ID is invalid, maybe?  When I click in the CiviCRM interface on the User ID, it takes me to https://example.org/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=1046 and says "Invalid user ID."  Indeed, there's no user 1046 - I wonder if that's a holdover from it being a Drupal site.

Yes so look in civicrm_uf_match. It probably has uf_id=1046 where contact_id = your contact. Try just updating the uf_id on that db row to match the wordpress id.

@Demerit is it okay to just do UPDATE civicrm_uf_match SET uf_id=1 WHERE contact_id=102?  Or does it need to be done programmatically to ensure consistency with other stuff?

I think we posted at the same time. Yes exactly.

Awesome, I've made the change and I'll wait a bit to see whether the ghouls stop spawning.

Okay, so I think this fixed it for me, no more new phantoms.  What's the best course of action to get this fixed?  I feel like having a dangling reference in civicrm_uf_match shouldn't cause thousands of contacts to get created, right?

Based on comments this was a migration that had a leftover civicrm_uf_match record pointing to a non-existent user record.
To also answer the last comment about how to avoid in future, one idea is a system status check that lists uf_match records that point to non-existent users or contacts.
